# Nested SELECT clause in SELECT , FROM or WHERE and differences

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

1.I would like to know when do we use the structure of sub-queries in the `select` clause?

2.If any query which is written in 1. structure has an equivalent in one of the other nested forms:

```
  SELECT ... from ... where .. IN (SELECT ...)
    SELECT ... from (SELECT ...)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I will refer to the first select as the outer select, and the second select as the inner select.

You would use `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)` if you want to find records that a similar to a record you know about. Items from the inner select can be compared to the outer select.

```
Get the population of cities which are in Texas
SELECT city, population FROM cities WHERE city IN (SELECT city FROM states WHERE state = 'Texas')
```

You would use `SELECT ... FROM ... (SELECT ...)` if you want to create a derived table for your statement. Items calculated on the inner select can then be used on the outer select.

```
Get employees who have earned more than $500 this week (derived table x)
SELECT name, ROUND(wages) FROM (SELECT name, per_hour * hours_worked AS wages FROM timesheet) AS x WHERE wages > 500
```

There is also a third way which is a correlated subquery, which would be displayed as `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... (= or > or < or != etc) (SELECT ...)` and is used when you want to select rows based on a calculation.

```
Get cities with bigger populations than 2 times the average
SELECT city, population FROM cities WHERE population > 2 * (SELECT AVG(population) FROM cities)
```